# React Router v4 Handling Path With Hash (Number Sign) Symbol

Tags: reactjs, hash, navigation, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use Twitch Login in my react application. Twitch is returning data with redirect uri as "http://yourwebsite.com/#accesstoken=13324324" but i can't handle it. React router is navigating to NotFound.

**Note:**
If i navigate to "http://yourwebsite.com/accesstoken=13324324" without "#" it navigate to Mainpage.

My App.js:

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <div className="bg"></div>
        <MasterPage></MasterPage>
        <div className="BrowserRouter">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={MainPage} />
            <Route path='/home/:id?' component={MainPage} />
            <Route path='/profile' component={Profile} />
            <Route path='/stream' component={Stream} />
            <Route path='/store' component={Market} />
            <Route component={NotFound} />{/*no match*/}
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
```

How can i handle it?

Comment: you can handle it on your notfound route. first check the hash. using the match param. if recognized - accesstoken. render or redirect else use notfound

Comment: thanks, it can solve my problem but it seems wrong way to resolve.